# I am trying to create UI programatically but the scroll view and text view is not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a UIViewController with a scroll view, a content view with fields added to it programatically. The text view has scroll disabled. As user types the text view grows in size but it does not move up above keyboard. Also the scroll is not scrolling the correct view. Please check the attached [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_6gStDDiUJs3FkqxOExehf3cWrUiFvNf/view?usp=sharing).

```
extension ScrollViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
        var newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        if newSize.height < 200 {
            newSize.height = 200
        }
        textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
        if let constraint = (body.constraints.filter { $0.firstAttribute == .height }.first) {
            constraint.constant = newSize.height
        }
        textView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

The constraint code:

```
func addConstraints() {
        // scroll view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0)
            ])
        // content view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0)
            ])
        // title text field
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            titleText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            titleText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            titleText.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: body.topAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            titleText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 31)
            ])
        // body text view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            body.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleText.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            body.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            body.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            body.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -40),
            body.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
        ])
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

[GrowingTextView](https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView)

As per your requirement textview is not enough. Please try and let me know if you find any issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ScrollViewController: UIViewController {
    private var notifs: [Any?] = []
    private lazy var navController: UINavigationController = {
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
        navVC.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        navVC.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        return navVC
    }()
    private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let sv = UIScrollView()
        sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return sv
    }()
    private lazy var contentView: UIView = {
        let cv = UIView()
        cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return cv
    }()
    private lazy var titleText: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        field.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
        field.placeholder = "Title"
        return field
    }()
    private lazy var body: UITextView = {
        let field = UITextView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        field.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addTextViewBorder(field)
        return field
    }()

    let labelTwo: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Scroll Bottom"
        label.backgroundColor = .green
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initUI()
        addConstraints()
        initEvents()
    }

    func getNavigationController() -> UINavigationController {
        return navController
    }

    func addTextViewBorder(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    }

    func initUI() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDidTap))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Save", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveDidTap))
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.addSubview(titleText)
        contentView.addSubview(body)
        body.delegate = self
        body.isScrollEnabled = false
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
        scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 2300)        
    }

    func addConstraints() {
        // scroll view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0)
            ])
        // content view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0)
            ])
        // title text field
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 10),
            titleText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            titleText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            titleText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 31)
            ])
        // body text view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            body.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleText.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            body.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            body.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            body.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            body.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
        ])
    }

    func initEvents() {
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewDidTap(recognizer:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        // Keyboard events
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notif:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notif:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    // MARK: - Selector

    @objc func cancelDidTap() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func saveDidTap() {

    }

    @objc func viewDidTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notif: Notification) {
        if let userInfo = notif.userInfo, let keyboardSize = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
            let kbHeight = keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
            keyboardHeight = kbHeight
            //  let bkgndRect = poemBody.superview!.frame
            //   poemBody.superview?.frame(forAlignmentRect: bkgndRect)
            //   scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: poemBody.frame.origin.y - keyboardHeight), animated: true)
        }
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notif: Notification) {
        let contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
        scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset
    }
}

extension ScrollViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
        var newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        if newSize.height < 200 {
            newSize.height = 200
        }
        textView.frame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
        if let constraint = (body.constraints.filter { $0.firstAttribute == .height }.first) {
            constraint.constant = newSize.height
        }
        textView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Use this code your problem will be solved.
The main problem with your code is anchoring **contentView** and you were giving **title text field bottomAnchor to body.topAnchor which causes your body text view height**.

Comment: Then use library [link] (https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView)